# Extracting Information from a complex string

Tags: python, string

Hi I have the following two columns in Panda Arrary. As You can see that the information in the second column has a lot of information. As far as I understand it is some form of a "list" but with double instead of single quotation marks.

```
 Customer Name  Details
Jacob   "[{""Name"":""Phone"",""Value"":""03477444556""},{""Name"":""Type"",""Value"":""Apartment""},{""Name"":""No - Name"",""Value"":""1210""},{""Name"":""Apartment N    me"",""Value"":""Khudadaad Height  E-11\/1""},{""Name"":""Street"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Sector"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Landmark"",""Value"":null}]"
John    "[{""Name"":""Phone"",""Value"":""03477444550""},{""Name"":""Type"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""No - Name"",""Value"":""10""},{""Name"":""Apartment Name"",""Val    e"":""Khudadaad Height  E-11\/1""},{""Name"":""Street"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Sector"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Landmark"",""Value"":null}]"
Smith   "[{""Name"":""Phone"",""Value"":""03475649292""},{""Name"":""Type"",""Value"":""House""},{""Name"":""No - Name"",""Value"":""1 a""},{""Name"":""Apartment Name""    ""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Street"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Sector"",""Value"":""f 7 3""},{""Name"":""Landmark"",""Value"":null}]"
Adam    "[{""Name"":""Phone"",""Value"":""03466700079""},{""Name"":""Type"",""Value"":""Office""},{""Name"":""No - Name"",""Value"":""ptcl head quarter""},{""Name"":""A    artment Name"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Street"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Sector"",""Value"":""g\/8\/4""},{""Name"":""Landmark"",""Value"":null}]"
Carlos  "[{""Name"":""Phone"",""Value"":""03466700079""},{""Name"":""Type"",""Value"":""Office""},{""Name"":""No - Name"",""Value"":""ptcl head quarter""},{""Name"":""A    artment Name"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Street"",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Sector"",""Value"":""g\/8\/4""},{""Name"":""Landmark"",""Value"":null}]"
Ali     "[{""Name"":""Phone"",""Value"":""03465403134""},{""Name"":""Type"",""Value"":""House""},{""Name"":""No - Name"",""Value"":""55-B ""},{""Name"":""Apartment Name    ",""Value"":null},{""Name"":""Street"",""Value"":""21""},{""Name"":""Sector"",""Value"":""F 10\/2""},{""Name"":""Landmark"",""Value"":null}]"
```

Anyhow this is how I'm interpreting this information. It contains seven different rows against each customer with each row containing within it four different values. So for the first customer Jacob the value in Row 1 and column 4 is " 03477444556 ". This row for each customer contains their phone number. Similarly, against each customer row 3 column 4 contains their location.

I'm interested in creating a column which would contain say the phone number for all customers. How can I go about it so that from the above I can get this:

```
Customer Name | Phone Number 
  Jacob         |  03477444556 
  John          | 034777444550 
  Smith         |  03475649292 
  Adam          |  03466700079 
  Carlos        |  03466700079 
  Ali           |  03465403132
```

And be able to do the above for any information contained within the master column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You haven't asked a question or provided a [mcve] explaining how your solution is deficient.  What is it you would like us to do?

Comment: Nevermind! fixed the format :)